# Could someone help me with creating a single output after a delay from my code?

Tags: python, numpy, loops, output

I'm using a thermal camera with Python code on my Raspberry Pi. I inserted some code yesterday that'll allow me to find the radius of where a fire is on the thermal camera and I'm going to output the theta in a different code.

What I'm having trouble with however is showcasing one output rather than a consistent output every second (or in respect to the refresh rate). Is there a way to accomplish this?

Here is my code below:

```
import time,board,busio
import numpy as np
import adafruit_mlx90640
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
extent = (-16, 16, -12.5, 12.5)

i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA, frequency=800000)
mlx = adafruit_mlx90640.MLX90640(i2c)
mlx.refresh_rate = adafruit_mlx90640.RefreshRate.REFRESH_1_HZ
mlx_shape = (24,32)

plt.ion()
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,7))
therm1 = ax.imshow(np.zeros(mlx_shape),vmin=0, vmax=60, extent=extent)
cbar = fig.colorbar(therm1)
cbar.set_label('Temperature [$^{\circ}$C]', fontsize=14)

frame = np.zeros((2432,))
t_array = []
np.array
print("Starting loop")
while True:
    t1 = time.monotonic()
    try:
        mlx.getFrame(frame)
        data_array = (np.reshape(frame,mlx_shape))
        therm1.set_data(np.reshape(frame,mlx_shape))
        therm1.set_clim(vmin=np.min(data_array))
        cbar.update_normal(therm1)
        plt.title("Max")
        plt.pause(0.001)
        t_array.append(time.monotonic() - t1)
        # fig.savefig('mlx90640_test_fliplr.png', dpi=300, facecolor = '#FCFCFC', bbox_inches='tight')

        highest_num = data_array[0][0]
        x = 0
        y = 0
        for i in range (len(data_array)):
            for j in range(len(data_array[i])):
                if data_array[x][y] < data_array[i][j]:
                    x = i
                    y = j
                    highest_num = data_array[i][j]

        idx = np.argmax(data_array)
        m, n = len(data_array), len(data_array[0])
        r, c = m - (idx // n) - 1 , idx % n
        y, x = r - (m // 2), c - (n // 2)
        radius  = math.sqrt( x x + y * y)
        theta = math.atan(y/x)
        theta = 180 * theta/math.pi
        print("Radius", radius)
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Return only one value?

Comment: use `break` after you print ? :)